# Preprocessing large and sparse images in deep learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning

It's a general question about better ways to preprocess large-sized and sparse images in deep learning.

By large, I mean the size is too big(e.g. 1024*1024*channels) for directly feeding into the deep learning pipeline, and won't easily fit in the available GPU memories.

By sparse, I mean the feature for detection is not evenly distributed so that cutting images into smaller pieces(e.g. 64*64) may defeat the purpose of locating it in large images. For example, it won't help to locate a farmhouse in the farmland by having 99 pictures of land and 1 picture of the house.

My current solution is using `PIL` to cut originals into smaller pieces and penalize False Negative(i.e. Farmhouse identified as land in the previous example).

I wonder if there are better solutions and pipelines to deal with such image data.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom data generator to feed data to your model. You don't need to load all the images together. You can load a single image or N(batch size) number of images at a time during training. Create a text/CSV with all the image file names and annotation data.

```
def datagenerator(batch_size):
df_x = load_your_image_file_paths
df_y = load_your_annotation_data
i = 0 #pointing to data index
while True: #keeping it alive until it finishes
    x = []
    y = []
    for j in range(batch_size):
        img = Image.open(df_x[i])
        anno = df_y[i]
        final_img = preprocess_as_you_want(img)
        final_anno = preprocess_your_annotation_if_needed(anno)
        x.append(final_img)
        y.append(final_anno)
        i += 1
        '''
        df_x should be circular. this function will be called so many times depending 
        on number of epochs. make sure i never get larger than the maximum index
        '''
        if i >= len(df_x):  
            i = 0 #starting from the beginning
    yield np.array(x),np.array(y)
```

Your generator is now ready to use. Let's train your model.

```
model.fit_generator(datagenerator(your_prefered_batch_size), 
                steps_per_epoch=total_data/batch_size, ...other_params)
```

You can do the same for validation data.

Comment: I see your point of using a smaller batch size, but sometimes a reasonably small batch size(e.g. 16) is still rather computationally intensive for architectures like Unet++, and even smaller batch sizes may fail to converge.

Comment: For some models, 16 is still a bigger number for batch size. You can even try  1-5 if your GPU memory is not much. That is not my point though. Using this function you're loading only 5 images at once if your batch size is 5. If you're not using any generator function, that means you're loading the whole dataset into your memory.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear but in asking this question, I already assumed batches/generators will be used. I was asking if there are other solutions from the image preprocessing perspective so that we don't have to sacrifice batch size too much.