# I want to convert my binary classification model to multiclass classification model I am taking labels using directory names

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

This is my code below it works fine for classification of two categories of images it takes labels based on directory names but whenever I add one more directory it stops working can someone help me
This is my code for image classification for images from two directories and two labels but when I convert it to three labels/ directories I get an error the error is posted below can someone help me solve the problem This if for image classification
I have tried removing the NumPy array I somewhere saw I need to just pass it through a CNN but I couldn't do that.
I am trying to make a classifier for pneumonia caused by a coronavirus and other disease using frontal chest x rays

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGeneratorfrom 
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.layers import AveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from imutils import paths
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import os

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments

# initialize the initial learning rate, number of epochs to train for,
# and batch size
INIT_LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 40
BS = 66

# grab the list of images in our dataset directory, then initialize
# the list of data (i.e., images) and class images
print("[INFO] loading images...")
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images('/content/drive/My Drive/testset/'))
data = []
labels = []

# loop over the image paths
for imagePath in imagePaths:
    # extract the class label from the filename
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]

    # load the image, swap color channels, and resize it to be a fixed
    # 224x224 pixels while ignoring aspect ratio
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224))

    # update the data and labels lists, respectively
    data.append(image)
    labels.append(label)

# convert the data and labels to NumPy arrays while scaling the pixel
# intensities to the range [0, 255]
data = np.array(data) / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)

# perform one-hot encoding on the labels
lb = LabelBinarizer()
labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)
labels = to_categorical(labels)

# partition the data into training and testing splits using 80% of
# the data for training and the remaining 20% for testing
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels,
    test_size=0.20, stratify=labels, random_state=42)

# initialize the training data augmentation object
trainAug = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=15,
    fill_mode="nearest")

# load the VGG16 network, ensuring the head FC layer sets are left
# off
baseModel = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,
    input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))

# construct the head of the model that will be placed on top of the
# the base model
headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(64, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(headModel)

# place the head FC model on top of the base model (this will become
# the actual model we will train)
model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)

# loop over all layers in the base model and freeze them so they will
# *not* be updated during the first training process
for layer in baseModel.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# compile our model
print("[INFO] compiling model...")
opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])

# train the head of the network
print("[INFO] training head...")
H = model.fit(
    trainAug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
    steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
    validation_data=(testX, testY),
    validation_steps=len(testX) // BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS)

# make predictions on the testing set
print("[INFO] evaluating network...")
predIdxs = model.predict(testX, batch_size=BS)

# for each image in the testing set we need to find the index of the
# label with corresponding largest predicted probability
predIdxs = np.argmax(predIdxs, axis=1)

# show a nicely formatted classification report
print(classification_report(testY.argmax(axis=1), predIdxs,
    target_names=lb.classes_))

# compute the confusion matrix and and use it to derive the raw
# accuracy, sensitivity, and specificity
cm = confusion_matrix(testY.argmax(axis=1), predIdxs)
total = sum(sum(cm))
acc = (cm[0, 0] + cm[1, 1]) / total
sensitivity = cm[0, 0] / (cm[0, 0] + cm[0, 1])
specificity = cm[1, 1] / (cm[1, 0] + cm[1, 1])

# show the confusion matrix, accuracy, sensitivity, and specificity
print(cm)
print("acc: {:.4f}".format(acc))
print("sensitivity: {:.4f}".format(sensitivity))
print("specificity: {:.4f}".format(specificity))

# plot the training loss and accuracy
N = EPOCHS
plt.style.use("ggplot")
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["loss"], label="train_loss")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["val_loss"], label="val_loss")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["accuracy"], label="train_acc")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["val_accuracy"], label="val_acc")
plt.title("Training Loss and Accuracy on COVID-19 Dataset")
plt.xlabel("Epoch #")
plt.ylabel("Loss/Accuracy")
plt.legend(loc="lower left")
plt.savefig("plot.png")

# serialize the model to disk
print("[INFO] saving COVID-19 detector model...")
model.save('/content/drive/My Drive/setcovid/model.h5', )
```

[This is the error I got in my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba2eg.png)

Comment: you can save a lot of coding by using f.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory. Documentation is at https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/. Since you have multiple classes set label_mode to categorical_crossentropy and do the same in model.compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few changes you need to make it work. The error you're getting is because of one-hot-encode. You're encoding your labels to one-hot twice.

```
lb = LabelBinarizer()
labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)
labels = to_categorical(labels)
```

Please remove the last line 'to_categorical' from your code. You will get the one-hot encode in the correct format. It will fix the error you're getting now.

And there is another problem I must mention. Your model output layer has only 2 neurons but you want to classify 3 classes. Please set the output layer neurons to 3.

```
headModel = Dense(3, activation="softmax")(headModel)
```

And you're now training with 3 classes, it's not binary anymore. You have to use another loss. I will recommend you to use categorical.

```
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])
```

You also forgot to import the followings. Add these imports too.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
```

And you're good to go.

Btw, I'm pretty much afraid of the batch size(66) you're using. I don't know which GPU you have but still, I would suggest you decrease the batch size.

Comment: hey @Nazmul Thank you I am running out of ram most of the ram is getting used while loading images anyway I can overcome that problem ?

Comment: Yes, you can. You will need to use a data generator. Idea is to load only images during training. You can easily write your own data generator by the following:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62316078/preprocessing-large-and-sparse-images-in-deep-learning/62316542#62316542 

or you can also use keras ImageDataGenerator(flow_from_directory).

Comment: can you help me could I get your email id or something to contact you this is my email id nihal.nihalani@gmail.com can you send me an email I am stuck on this and I am not getting through with it.